# Why can't I create a `hardlink` to a file from a "mount --bind" directory on the same filesystem?

Tags: mount, ln, bind-mount

#### Original Problem

I have a file on one filesystem: `/data/src/file`

and I want to hard link it to: `/home/user/proj/src/file`

but `/home` is on one disk, and `/data` is on another so I get an error:

```
$ cd /home/user/proj/src
$ ln /data/src/file .
ln: failed to create hard link './file' => '/data/src/file': Invalid cross-device link
```

Okay, so I learned I can't hard link across devices.  Makes sense.

#### Problem at hand

So I thought I'd get fancy and bind mount a `src` folder that's on `/data`'s file system:

```
$ mkdir -p /data/other/src
$ cd /home/user/proj
$ sudo mount --bind /data/other/src src/
$ cd src
$ # (now we're technically on `/data`'s file system, right?)
$ ln /data/src/file .
ln: failed to create hard link './file' => '/data/src/file': Invalid cross-device link
```

Why does this still not work?

#### Workaround

I know I have this setup right because I can make the hard link as long as I'm in the "real" `/data` directory instead of the bound one.

```
$ cd /data/other/src
$ ln /data/src/file .
$ # OK
$ cd /home/user/proj/src
$ ls -lh
total 35M
-rw------- 2 user user 35M Jul 17 22:22 file

$
```

#### Some System Info

```
$ uname -a
Linux <host> 4.10.0-24-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 14 08:14:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ findmnt
.
.
.
├─/home                               /dev/sdb8   ext4       rw,relatime,data=ordered
│ └─/home/usr/proj/src             /dev/sda2[/other/src]
│                                                 ext4       rw,relatime,data=ordered
└─/data                               /dev/sda2   ext4       rw,relatime,data=ordered

$ mountpoint -d /data
8:2

$ mountpoint -d /home/usr/proj/src/
8:2
```

*Note*: I manually changed the file and directory names to make the situation more clear, so there may be a typo or two in the command readouts.

Comment: It does not matter where you mount folder. They are physicall on different partitions. Each partition has its own file table and hardlink is just record in this table.

Comment: The point here is that files are NOT on physically different partitions. It's the same filesystem from the same partition. The difference is the bind mount.

Comment: The bind mount is merely a fiction. It does not change the data structures on the disks. The file systems are still physically separate.

Comment: But when I create the hard link on `/data` I can access the inode from the bind mount directory, so either the bind mount must be on the same partition as `/data`, or the hard link is working across devices, which should be illegal, but works anyway.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a disappointing lack of comments in the [code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e06fdaf40a5c021dd4a2ec797e8b724f07360070/fs/namei.c#L4275).  It's as if no-one ever thought it useful, since the time bind mounts were implemented in v2.4.  Surely all you'd need to do is substitute `.mnt->mnt_sb` where it says `.mnt`...

> > Because it gives you a security boundary around a subtree.
>
> PS: that had been discussed quite a few times, but to avoid searches:
>   consider e.g. mount --bind /tmp /tmp; now you've got a situation when
>   users can't create links to elsewhere no root fs, even though they
>   have /tmp writable to them. Similar technics works for other isolation
>   needs - basically, you can confine rename/link to given subtree. IOW,
>   it's a deliberate feature. Note that you can bind a bunch of trees
>   into chroot and get predictable restrictions regardless of how the
>   stuff might get rearranged a year later in the main tree, etc.

-- [Al Viro](https://lists.gt.net/linux/kernel/855705#855705)

There's a concrete example further down the thread

> Whenever we get mount -r --bind working properly (which I use to place
>   copies of necessary shared libraries inside chroot jails while
>   allowing page cache sharing), this feature would break security.
>
> ```
> mkdir /usr/lib/libs.jail
> for i in $LIST_OF_LIBRARIES; do
> ln /usr/lib/$i /usr/lib/libs.jail/$i
> done
> mount -r /usr/lib/libs.jail /jail/lib
> chown prisoner /usr/log/jail
> mount /usr/log/jail /jail/usr/log
> chrootuid /jail prisoner /bin/untrusted &
> ```
>
> Although protections should be enough, but I'd rather avoid having the
>   prisoner link /jail/lib/libfoo.so (write returns EROFS) to
>   /jail/usr/log where it's potentially writeable.

Answer (score -2):

The reason you can't do cross-device linking is because you introduce ambiguities. The directory entry for the file contains (in simple systems) the i-node number for the file concerned. A hard link (just another directory entry) also has to contain the same i-node number. This is fine, but i-node numbers are only unique within a single file system (they are usually a dense set starting at 1).

Your bind mount doesn't fix that problem. Yes, it constructs a kind of 'fiction' of the structure, but what it doesn't do is re-number all the i-nodes on one file system to make sure they are all unique across both the file systems concerned! That would be silly.

This restriction has always been there on UNIX systems. The symbolic link was invented partly to solve this. I know they aren't functionally quite the same, but they are usually OK.

Try a symbolic link? (`ln -s`)

Comment: There would be no name for any inode renumbering here. There is only one underlying filesystem, with two views.

Comment: One reason I didn't want a symbolic link was because my paths were long and it was messy doing an `ls -l`.  Kinda silly reasoning at first, but then it lead to a rabbit hole and I got curious as to what was going on with the hard links...

Comment: @Gilles, that is what I was saying. The point I was making was that inode renumbering would be ridiculous. No idea why a correct answer was downvoted.

Comment: You get the conclusion right, but your explanation is wrong in so many places that your answer as a whole is very misleading. See sourcejedi's answer for a good explanation.

Comment: I see no errors at all, although I admit I could have been clearer.