# bind mounting source to itself

Tags: filesystems, mount, bind-mount

What does `mount --bind /dir1 /dir1` do? I've read https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt however it doesn't give a clear explanation. Looks like it is valid not only for directories, but also for files.

Answer (score 10):

This works exactly the same as the general case `mount --bind /dir1 /dir2`.  All you need to know about the special case is that it is well defined and does not recurse infinitely.

(For example, files can be self-bind mounted because files can be bind-mounted).

The special case is less pointless than it first sounds, for two reasons.

### 1. You can set bind mount options, e.g. to limit possible operations

> After this call the same contents are accessible in two places. 
>   One can also remount a single file (on a single file).  It's also
>   possible    to use the bind mount to create a mountpoint from a
>   regular directory, for example:
>
> ```
>       mount --bind foo foo
> ```
>
> The  bind mount call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem,
>   not possible submounts.  The entire file hierarchy including submounts
>   is    attached a second place by using:
>
> ```
>       mount --rbind olddir newdir
> ```
>
> Note that the filesystem mount options will remain the same as
>   those on the original mount point.
>
> mount(8) since v2.27 allows to change the mount options by passing
>   the relevant options along with --bind.  For example:
>
> ```
>       mount -o bind,ro foo foo
> ```
>
> This feature is not supported by the Linux kernel; it is
>   implemented in userspace by an additional mount(2) remounting system 
>   call.   This    solution is not atomic.
>
> The alternative (classic) way to create a read-only bind mount is
>   to use the remount operation, for example:
>
> ```
>       mount --bind olddir newdir
>       mount -o remount,bind,ro olddir newdir
> ```
>
> Note  that  a read-only bind will create a read-only mountpoint
>   (VFS entry), but the original filesystem superblock will still be
>   writable,    meaning that the olddir will be writable, but the newdir
>   will be read-only.
>
> It's also possible to change nosuid, nodev, noexec, noatime,
>   nodiratime and relatime VFS entry  flags  by  "remount,bind" 
>   operation.  It's    impossible to change mount options recursively
>   (for example with -o rbind,ro).

Another use of mount options is to set the "propagation flags".  These are specifically what `sharedsubtree.txt` explains.  They can definitely be confusing.  They're also outlined in `man mount`.

I only have one tip to offer: The doc claims shared subtrees were needed in order to propagate mounts of removable devices into a "slave" mount namespace.  However a more critical motivation is to be able to *unmount* your removable device, after you've started a sandboxed process in a "slave" mount namespace.

### 2. It creates a boundary that files cannot be moved or linked across

Apparently this is desired partly [in order to avoid bypassing the limitations imposed above, and partly because hardlinks can be really horrible for security and it could be useful to restrict them a bit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/380033/29483).